# Bounding the size of consecutive sums of independent Bernoullis

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables that take the values 1 and 0 each with probability 1/2.

Is the following statement true?

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $k = k(\epsilon)>0$ such that

$$
\mathbb{P} \left\{ \left| \sum_{i=a}^b X_i - \frac{b-a}{2} \right| < k \sqrt{b-a} \; \;\text{ for all }0 \leq a<b \right\} > 1 - \epsilon.
$$

Why or why not?

Based on the answer, I might have follow up questions...

Comment: No. Let $S_b=X_1+\cdots+X_b-\frac12b$. By the law of iterated logarithm, even the (a priori smaller) supremum $$\sup_{b\geqslant1}\frac{|S_b|}{\sqrt{b}}$$ is almost surely infinite.

Comment: If instead I change $\sqrt{b-a}$ to $(b-a)^{1/2 + \epsilon}$, is that strong enough?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I see how to get that result with changing the endpoint $b$, but I'm not sure how to do it when the starting point $a$ is also variable...